# How to rewrite this LINQ query with lambda expressions?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have this query which I am having a hard time writing it with the lambda expressions.

```
var userRoles = from ur in db.Set<IdentityUserRole>()
                  join r in db.Roles
                    on ur.RoleId equals r.Id
                  where ur.UserId == userId
                  select r.Name;
```

I get error messages with the `Where()` clause.

```
db.Set<IdentityUserRole>()
     .Join(db.Roles, ur => ur.RoleId, r => r.Id, (ur, r) => r)
     .Select(r => r.Name)
     .Where(x => x.)
```

After the dot operator in the `Where` clause, I cannot find the `UserId`

Comment: What is error message? And can you show lambdas you are tried?

Comment: Have you tried linqpad... Copy Paste your query in that and it will return you the Lambda Expression..

Comment: No, didn't know about Linqpad until you mentioned about it. Will look into it now.

Comment: Put the select after the where.  You are trying to use `.UserId` on a string object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `UserId`, because you already selected `r.Name` (`r.Name` does not have a property of `UserId`).

So just like `select` being after `where` in the other form, just re-order to put the `Where` before the `Select`:

```
db.Set<IdentityUserRole>()
  .Join(db.Roles, ur => ur.RoleId, r => r.Id, (ur, r) => r)
  .Where(x => x.UserId == userId) //where first,
  .Select(r => r.Name) //then select from the filtered results!
```

When something does not work when chaining a number of LINQ statements, it can help to debug by separating these out:

```
var join = db.Set<IdentityUserRole>()
  .Join(db.Roles, ur => ur.RoleId, r => r.Id, (ur, r) => r).ToList();
var where = join.Where(x => x.UserId == userId).ToList();
var select = where.Select(r => r.Name).ToList();
```

You can then hover over the variable names and double check that the *type* is what you expect, and if it compiles, you can look at the intermediate data and perhaps see why it might not be working.

That being said, I'm not sure why you would need to change to use this syntax if the other is working properly.

Comment: When I do that, I am not getting to select `Name` for the `Select` clause. It's like either or, when I make it `(ur, r) => ur` I can choose UserId. But cannot choose `Name`?

Comment: @StraightUp I updated my answer a bit: try splitting this into multiple statements and verify the type from each is what you expect.

Comment: Because I was using the other syntax in a method and calling it in a list and setting it to a `RolesList`. But I was getting an error message saying "This method is not supported against a materialized query result". So, I thought changing it to lambda expression query might solve the issue.

Comment: There is no difference between a lambda expression query and a query syntax query except the query syntax is unfortunately more limited in C# - the compiler just translates the query syntax into lambda syntax.

Comment: There are some questions related to that problem that might help: https://www.google.com/search?q=This%20method%20is%20not%20supported%20against%20a%20materialized%20query%20result